# Can IF be used to start a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a query that looks like this:

```
mysql_query("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM predict WHERE uid=$i AND bid=$j)
            THEN UPDATE predict SET predict_tfidf=$predict_tfidf WHERE uid=$i AND bid=$j
            ELSE INSERT INTO predict (uid, bid, predict_tfidf) VALUES('$i','$j','$predict_tfidf')
            END IF")or die(mysql_error());
```

But it dies and mysql tells me to check the syntax near `IF EXISTS(....)`

Can we not use an IF statement to start a mysql query?

[EDIT] Thanks for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` tip, but what if I don't have any primary or unique keys in the table?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do that (unless in stored procedure, and even then the syntax would be different)

Check `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! What if I don't have a primary or unique key in that table?

Comment: If yu don't have a primary key, create one. In relational database a table without a primary key is generally not the best idea. Just judging from your query above, it seems that (uid,bid) is a candidate for a primary key in this table.